# Error in My First Titanium Mobile Project

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am new to Titanium Studio (I  am using Titanium Studio-2.1.0GA on WindowsXP).  I added the Android SDK to the Titanium, but I am able to open the emulators as well. But when I run my first mobile project, the following error is displaying in console.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1  
[ERROR] Invalid number of parameters  
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:  
[ERROR] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):  
[ERROR]   File "C:\Documents and Settings\shyam.sundar\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2206, in <module> 
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)  
[ERROR]   File "C:\Documents and Settings\shyam.sundar\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1976, in build_and_run  
[ERROR]     for avd_props in avd.get_avds(self.sdk):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Documents and Settings\shyam.sundar\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.0.GA\android\avd.py", line 23, in get_avds  
[ERROR]     for line in run.run([sdk.get_android(),'list','target'],debug=False).split("\n"):  
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Java SDK do you have? I installed 1.7 and this problem went away.